how to write a function doing tuple permutations?
I'm trying to write a function that would convert a tuple-like type to a tuple containing all permutations of arguments. Something like: auto permute(auto&& like_tuple) -> tuple<all_type_permutations>
This is equivalent to finding all permutations of an index_sequence because you can always use it to convert the tuples. It's understandable that compiler can't do more than a handful of arguments due to n! complexity. But I find it tedious (and error-prone) writing all possible permutations by hand. Can it be done recursively?
Here is what I've got so far (see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7We7b5GMK)
template<size_t N>
auto permute_sequence(index_sequence<N>)
{
    return index_sequence<N>{};
}

template<size_t N1, size_t N2>
auto permute_sequence(index_sequence<N1, N2>)
{
    return index_sequence<N1, N2, N2, N1>{};
}

template<size_t N1, size_t N2, size_t N3>
auto permute_sequence(index_sequence<N1, N2, N3>)
{
    return index_sequence<N1, N2, N3, N1, N3, N2, N2, N1, N3,
        N2, N3, N1, N3, N1, N2, N3, N2, N1>{};
}

template<size_t ... N>
auto permute(auto&& t, index_sequence<N...>)
{
    return tuple(std::get<N>(t)...);
}

auto permute(auto&& t)
{
    return permute(t, permute_sequence(
        make_index_sequence<tuple_size_v<remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>>{})
        );
}



What is the point of doing permutations for tuples of any size when this very thing, for vectors, already exists in <algorithm>? + as you said, your functions generate tuples with n! template arguments i.e. memory consumption growing very fast when the standard method only keeps the vector of size n at any given moment.

@Atmo -- tuple is not vector

I obviously never said tuples are vectors...

Basically, if you let these tuples live on the stack, you can generate permutations for only 7-8 items. With 9-tuples of size_t integers, the generated tuple contains 9! permutations, each of 9 elements, each element being of size of 8 bytes (on 64-bit architectures); total: about 25MB .... for 9 integers.... And it only gets more ridiculous from there: the entire memory of my computer is not enough to store all the permutations of only 12 integers at the same time. So I think the least you can do is explain in your question why you are doing things this way, don't you think?

You can use the existing std::next_permutation to generate the index of all permutations at compile-time, and then assemble the final tuple through index_sequence:
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t... Is>
constexpr auto gen_permus_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Is)> idx{Is...};
  std::vector<decltype(idx)> permus;
  do permus.push_back(idx);
  while (std::ranges::next_permutation(idx).found);
  return permus;
}

template<size_t... Is>
constexpr auto gen_permus(std::index_sequence<Is...> seq) {
  constexpr auto permu_size = gen_permus_impl(seq).size();
  std::array<std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Is)>, permu_size> permus;
  std::ranges::copy(gen_permus_impl(seq), permus.begin());
  return permus;
}

template<class Tuple, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto gen_permu(Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return std::tuple(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template<class Tuple>
constexpr auto permute(Tuple t) {
  using Seq = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>;
  constexpr static auto permu = gen_permus(Seq{});
  return [&]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::tuple_cat(gen_permu(t, typename as_sequence<permu[Is]>::type{})...);
  }(std::make_index_sequence<permu.size()>{});
}

Demo

Wow, didn't expect std::ranges to do the job at compile time. Probably impractical, because it takes forever to compile, but beautiful nonetheless.

@Gene the impracticality is in the heart of your question. There's nothing special about <ranges> here; it only provides convenient functions for std::copy and std::next_permutation. Those are the fundamental algorithms you need anyway. No solution to your question with significantly better performance than this answer exists. Maybe a better polished revision you need; but that would be your own part to play.

std::vector can be trivially avoided since the number of permutations is known a priori (factorial(tuple_size_v<T>)), which may improve compile times

@Red.Wave -- actually a fast compiling solution exists, it's just ugly. Since index permutations are known beforehand, you can just print them and copy the indexes in the code. There must be a faster solution, compiler for some reason is very slow executing ranges algorithms at compile time, it should have been taking a fraction of a second.

<ranges> is the first experience with constraint templates. Other than that, it's mostly a wrapper around iterative algorithms. But since constraints are checked at compile-time too, the overhead is added. After creating index permutations, there's no point in  generating tuple perms. Just apply the indice and std::tie in a function.
